# pagetab dialog getting error

Tags: facebook, api, url

Getting Error when i try to add a new pagetab.

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

inserted for

YOUR_APP_ID = id of app
YOUR_URL=www.xxxxxxxxx

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Any hints would be very helpful.
Wondering, that i did this some weeks before without trouble.

Thanx

Comment: Is the value for 'YOUR_URL' on the same server that you host the page tab itself? It must match the URLs in your app settings

Comment: Hi Igy, thanx for your answer. Just got it some minutes ago:

YOUR_URL must be the final url to be added and not just the domain name

How do i mark this thread here as answered?

Answer (score 0):

The value you're using for `YOUR_URL` must be a URL on one of the domains specified in the `app domains` value in the app settings and/or derived from the page tab URL you're using in the 'Page Tab' settings